# Dynamic pivot where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dynamic pivot written as below, I need to add a `where` clause

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@uniqId varchar(50);

set @uniqId = 'IN0s3Z0n8z4v'

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.DisplayLabel) 
        FROM [dbo].[CountyCaseUserData] c where UniqueEntryId = @uniqId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'') 

print @cols
 set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
 from 
        (
            SELECT UserInput, DisplayLabel,row_number() 
                       over (partition by DisplayLabel order by  CCId) AS No
            from [dbo].[CountyCaseUserData] where UniqueEntryId = @uniqId
       ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(UserInput)
            for DisplayLabel in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p ';


 execute(@query)
```

But when executing, I get a message

> Must declare the scalar variable "@uniqId"

What am I missing here?

Comment: First declare `@uniqid` then either `where UniqueEntryId = '''+ @uniqId + ''') x` or use `sp_executesql` to pass as a parameter.

Comment: The execute doesn't know the variables. So you need to add it to the @query like Les H suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as what others pointed out,

change  `execute(@query)`

to

```
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@uniqId varchar(50)', @uniqId
```